# Android GoogleMaps - Inheriting a map fragment from a base fragment activity abstract class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm working on a project where I am switching between two map activities.

The structure I'm attempting is something like this:

```
BaseMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity

MapsActivity1 extends BaseMapsActivity

MapsActivity2 extends BaseMapsActivity
```

In order to prevent code duplication.  I'd like to put my Google API client code in the base Activity and then some map styling code in the base onMapReady() and simply make changes for each sub activity afterwards (adding markers, etc).

My question is, how can I prepare this mapFragment with style and location logic in the base class, and then inflate a frame layout with the fragment in the sub activities to modify it?  How would the steps of this process play out?  Is this even possible?

```
public abstract class BaseMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

public static final String TAG = "BaseMapsActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.base_map_activity);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

and for the sub activity 1...

```
public class MapsActivity1 extends BaseMapsActivity implements LocationListener, View.OnClickListener {
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

private GoogleMap mMap;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;
private DatabaseReference databaseRef;


private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity1";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.onMapReady(mMap);
```

and the second activity...

```
public class MapsActivity2 extends BaseMapsActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    View.OnClickListener, OnProgressListener {


//    GoogleMap mMap;
private static GoogleMap mMap;




SeekBar colorSeek;


private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private Bundle mapSpots;
private Button backToMap;
private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarListener;

private LatLng user;


private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity2";
private static final int HUE_MAX = 360;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onMapReady(mMap);
```

Thanks T

Comment: Your idea and your code looks fine for me, what are the problems that you are having?

Comment: @jonathanrz getting null pointer exception : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMapType(int)' on a null object reference ----- It's coming from the super.onMapReady()

Comment: @jonathanrz I think I figured it out!  Rather than having super.onMapReady called in onCreate, I need to call it at the top of the onMapReady override in the child activity.

Comment: @jonathanrz thank you for checking it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to call super.onMapReady(Bundle savedInstanceState) not in the onMapReady override in the child class, so instead of:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onMapReady(mMap);
```

It needs to be this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onMapReady(mMap);

@Override
protected void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    mMap = googleMap;
    super.onMapReady(mMap);
```